# Query to select related data from two tables in which one table has no related fields in third table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by

I have three tables in my Oracle db:

```
Peoples:
IdPerson PK
Name
Surname

Earnings:
IdEarning PK
IdPerson
EarningValue

Awards:
IdAward PK
IdPerson FK
AwardDescription
```

So one person can have many earnings, one earning or can have no any earnings. Also one person can have many awards, one award, or no any award.

I have to select `Surname` and `AwardDescription` but only for people who have any earnings, because it is possible to have some award but, also don't have any earning!

My problem is to make a correct `group by` statement. I use query posted below and I am selecting surname of person with a description of award, but it is duplicating for each row in Earnings for this person.

```
SELECT AwardDescription, Surname
FROM Awards
INNER JOIN People ON People.IdPerson= Awards.IdPerson
INNER JOIN Earnings ON Earnings .IdPerson= People.IdPerson;
```

How to group it and avoid duplicating rows for each earning of person?
One person can be in many rows, but with different awards.

Comment: do a left outer join instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `DISTINCT` to your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AwardDescription, Surname
FROM Awards
    INNER JOIN People ON People.IdPerson= Awards.IdPerson
    INNER JOIN Earnings ON Earnings .IdPerson= People.IdPerson;
```

Or another option is to use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT AwardDescription, Surname
FROM Awards
    INNER JOIN People P ON P.IdPerson= Awards.IdPerson
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Earnings E
    WHERE P.IdPerson = E.IdPerson);
```

Comment: If i am using a distinct, it is not returning rows when the award name is duplicated for each person. When i trying the second option , then some people that have earnings have not been returned in any row - i try now to analyse why

Comment: @user2838197 -- `distinct` won't work if that's what you need.  But `exists` should - if those people that have earnings don't have awards, they won't show us with `exists`.  You'll have to use an outer join -- `from people p left join awards a on p.idperson = a.idperson`.

Comment: Sorry! The exists works well! I have many data here, and i was a bit confused.. but i sorted it out. With Exists it works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do a `left outer join` among the tables like

```
SELECT p.Surname, a.AwardDescription, e.EarningValue     
FROM People p
LEFT JOIN Awards a ON p.IdPerson= a.IdPerson
LEFT JOIN Earnings e ON e.IdPerson= p.IdPerson
WHERE a.AwardDescription IS NOT NULL
OR e.EarningValue IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question -- the problem is duplicating rows, not outer joins.  OP says `only for people who have any earnings` -- this will return all awards.